# Java JTable saving a single cell at a time to a database

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-update, jtable

I'm new at Java so this is probably an easy issue to a long time Java programmer.

Anyways, my issue is with using the **JTable**. I am wanting to **load/save the data** in that JTable. Problem being is that I am not sure **how to go about saving a cell that the user has changed** in some way.

The click event looks like this that I have:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class EditableTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
     String[] columnTitles;
     Object[][] dataEntries;
     int rowCount;

     public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
         //Any change to the table
         dataEntries[row][column] = value;
     }
}
```

**This function fires off just fine whenever I change any of the cells** in the jTable. It also **gives me the Row and the Column number** from that **edited cell** along with, of course, **the value that it was changed to**. But my question is that:

> **How would I go about saving this data into my database if its just a cell value at a time?**

My database structure looks like this (which has the same layout/order as the jTable structure):

```
ID  | Data_script | data_status | data_users | data_error | data_rundate | lastUserWhoMod
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | Inquiries   | Passed      | Bob        | No errors  | 01/20/2019   | Bob
2   | Reporting   | Passed      | Jenny      | No errors  | 01/20/2019   | Bob
3   | Background  | Failed      | Bob        | Lines 4,8  | 01/20/2019   | Jenny 
4   | Maintenance | Passed      | George     | No errors  | 01/20/2019   | Bob
```

So as an example, if I change the **1st row 3rd column** which is **data_users** from **Jenny** to **George** then how would I **map** that **to the database** in order to **save it in the correct spot** (row, column)?

Answer (score 1):

Need to consider also the table_key (pk assume id).

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
     Object obj_key = dataEntries[row][0]; //assume id
     //Any change to the table
     dataEntries[row][column] = value; 

     //obj_key mapped inside method from Object to int
     //get appropriate field_name from column index
     run_sql(obj_key, row, column) 

 }
```

Raw update query

```
update table_name
set [computed_field_name] = column_new_value (dataEntries[row][column])
where id = obj_key
```

Since you know ahead corresponding names for cols, need also to set up properly 
field_name ( if col=1 then data_script ...etc )

Answer (score 0):

1. add a variable

   int lastChanged = 0;
2. In setValueAt, add

   lastChanged = row;

and call a function in a separate thread to update the database for the whole record, pointed out by lastChanged. That function must reset the value of lastChanged to -1.
The call to the DB must be performed in a separate thread, since setValueAt will be executing in the thread Java uses to paint the GUI's.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn’t make much sense to me. I’m looking to know what the query would need to be in order to save that one cell.